# How to set sort predicate in sortedcontainers.SortedDict?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, collections, sortedcontainers

Is there a way to sort items in `sortedcontainers.SortedDict` by value, so that SortedDict always maintains its items in sorted order based on values, not on keys?

The standard example from [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) shows that items in SortedDict will be automatically sorted by dictionary key:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
>>> sd = SortedDict({'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> sd
SortedDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
```

So far, I managed to sort items in dict by value(datetime) during creation time:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
>>> d = {'a': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}, 'b': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}, 'z': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}, 'c': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}}
>>> sd = SortedDict(lambda key: d[key]['datetime'], d)
>>> sd
SortedDict(<function <lambda> at 0x101e86598>, {'a': {'datetime': datetime.datetime('...')}, 'b': {'datetime': datetime.datetime('...')}, 'z': {'datetime': datetime.datetime('...')}, 'e': {'datetime': datetime.datetime('...')}})
```

However, when I'm trying to add a new item, it throws the key error exception:

```
>>> sd['d'] = {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}
>>> KeyError: 'd'
```

Comment: That makes sense. The item isn't in the dictionary yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to sortedcontainers, but my impression is this is not possible as such. Have a look instead at the related package [Sorted Collections](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcollections/index.html) and specifically [ValueSortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcollections/valuesorteddict.html). You will need to refactor your code a bit, but you could do something like:

```
d = {'a': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}, 'b': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}, 'z': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}, 'c': {'datetime': datetime.datetime.now()}}
vsd = ValueSortedDict()
for k, v in d.items():                                                                                                                                              
    vsd[k] = v['datetime']
vsd['d'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```